# How to trim figure caption in the \listoffigures

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, captions, books

I want to trim the figure caption to show part of the caption, say the first sentence. In the same time, I do not want to cut from the actual caption in the document itself. I need the full explanation of the figure but not in the list of figures. How to achieve this?

This is the script sample:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{(Chapter Name)}

\section{Real Analysis}
\begin{figure}
\caption{A very long figure caption here. I need to display part of it because this very long caption does not look right in the list of figures. Nevertheless, I need this full description in the caption. I just do not want all of it to appear in the listoffigures}
\end{figure}
\section{Role of LUB Axiom}
```

\end{document}

This is what it appears int he list of figures.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can use `\caption[Short version]{Really, really long version}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the caption command has an optional entry, which is shown in the list of figures/tables/etc.: `\caption[Short title for lof]{Long title for document}`
Your document would look like this:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{(Chapter Name)}

\section{Real Analysis}
\begin{figure}
\caption[A short caption for the lof]{A very long figure caption here. I need to display part of it because this very long caption does not look right in the list of figures. Nevertheless, I need this full description in the caption. I just do not want all of it to appear in the listoffigures}
\end{figure}
\section{Role of LUB Axiom}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are my savior!!! This is not as automated as I would liked, but I can definitely use that and I wanted to thank you! (now comes the fun – I have 50+ figures).